# `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

I have the following bit of code:

```
load 'Point.rb'
class Triangle

    def initialize(x, y , z)
        if !x.is_a?(Point) || !y.is_a?(Point) || !z.is_a?(Point)
            puts "Invalid data, a Triangle can only be initialized through points"
        else
            @x=x
            @y=y
            @z=z
            @type=type(x, y, z)
        end
    end

    def type(x, y, z)
        if x.distance(y) == y.distance(z) && y.distance(z) == z.distance(x)
            return "equilateral"
        elsif x.distance(y)== y.distance(z) || y.distance(z) == z.distance(x) || z.distance(x) == x.distance(y)
            return "isosceles"
        else
            return "scalene"
        end
    end

    attr_accessor :type
end
```

I'm calling the method like this:

```
load 'Triangle.rb'

x=Point.new(0,0)
y=Point.new(1,1)
z=Point.new(2,0)
triangle=Triangle.new x, y, z
puts triangle.type
```

The class `Point` is as follows:

```
class Point

    def initialize (x=0, y=0)
        @x=x.to_i
        @y=y.to_i
    end

    def ==(point)
        if @x==point.x && @y==point.y
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    def distance(point)
        Math.hypot((@x-point.x),(@y-point.y))
    end

    attr_accessor :y
    attr_accessor :x
end
```

The error is as follows:

```
Triangle.rb:11:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
    from Triangle_test.rb:6:in `new'
    from Triangle_test.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Please tell if the whole code is just garbage.

Comment: you haven't shown the place where you call `.new`. Also, what is this `type` method you're calling?

Comment: Where exactly (filename and line number) is that error raised? How do you try to initialize an instance? How is `type` defined?

Comment: There, I tried to clarify as much as i could. I`m sorry if that made the question too long.

Comment: "please tell me nicely if the whole code is just garbage" - The code is, _ahem_, not fully adhering to [ruby style guidelines](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). But you almost got it working. That is what matters.

Comment: Also, friendly advice: learn how to debug and investigate problems. That's one of the most important skills a programmer can have. In your case, the error message points directly to a line of code. That's the first thing you should look at.

Comment: Yes, it is. .............

Comment: i´m sorry, i promise never to try anything new again.

Answer (score 3):

In your `Triangle` class you have method `type` which accepts three parameters, and then below you have `attr_accessor :type` which overwrites that 3-parameters method with a parameterless getter.

That's why you get that error when you do this in the initializer

```
@type=type(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i just changed the name of the three parameter "type" method to "triangle_type".

Comment: @azurox Yep, that should fix the problem.

Comment: @azurox Oh and BTW (since you're new to stackoverflow), you should accept the best/most helpful (the green checkmark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cleaned-up version of your code:

- removed unneeded if's
- removed unneeded return's
- defined a private `calculate_type` method
- replaced `attr_accessor` with `attr_reader`
- renamed `x,y,z` with `a,b,c` to avoid confusion between coordinates and points

---

```
class Point
  attr_reader :x, :y
  def initialize(x = 0, y = 0)
    @x = x.to_i
    @y = y.to_i
  end

  def ==(point)
    @x == point.x && @y == point.y
  end

  def distance(point)
    Math.hypot((@x - point.x), (@y - point.y))
  end
end

class Triangle
  attr_reader :a, :b, :c, :type

  def initialize(a, b, c)
    raise 'Invalid data, a Triangle can only be initialized through points' unless [a, b, c].all? { |p| p.is_a?(Point) }
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
    @type = calculate_type
  end

  private

  def calculate_type
    if a.distance(b) == b.distance(c) && b.distance(c) == c.distance(a)
      'equilateral'
    elsif a.distance(b) == b.distance(c) || b.distance(c) == c.distance(a) || c.distance(a) == a.distance(b)
      'isosceles'
    else
      'scalene'
    end
  end
end

a = Point.new(0, 0)
b = Point.new(1, 1)
c = Point.new(2, 0)
triangle = Triangle.new a, b, c
puts triangle.type
# isosceles
```

Comment: Thank you, i am still very new to all of this. Basically we'll start having class on ruby tomorrow but i just got excited and started learning by myself. Before reading and googling bits of your code i had no idea that exceptions existed in ruby nor that you could create private methods. The help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is an old question but I'm new to ruby so I'll just leave it here in case it helps other lost souls like myself*

A later version of the midi-smtp-server library I was using started requiring all arguments to be named, so for example in my case where I was passing:

```rb
server = MySmtpd.new(1234, "0.0.0.0")
```

I had to change to:

```rb
server = MySmtpd.new(ports: 1234, hosts: "0.0.0.0")
```